# How to get rid of the view state caching for ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, viewstate

I make up a dynamic table in a code behind file using the code as such:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" EnableViewState="false" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</table>
```

and here's how I build it up in Page_Load():

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl trContainer0 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("tr");
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl tdContainer00 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("td");

//Time variable
DateTime dtDateTime0 = DateTime.Now();

//Time (must be localized)
TextBox tbxAtTime = new TextBox();
tbxAtTime.EnableViewState = false;
tbxAtTime.ID = "myTime1";
tbxAtTime.Text = dtDateTime0.ToShortTimeString();

tdContainer00.Controls.Add(tbxAtTime);
trContainer0.Controls.Add(tdContainer00);
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(trContainer0);
```

This loads up the `tbxAtTime` text box correctly, but the problem happens when I change the culture from my custom control on that page that makes it to load (via post-back.) In that case the `tbxAtTime` text box seems to retain the old value that it got during the initial loading of the page, even though when I put a break-point in the code, it shows the new text (with accordance to a new culture.)

So what's the trick here?